# Google Protocol Buffers: No operator[]?

Tags: c++, caffe, protocol-buffers

According to the [google developer docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field) the protocol buffer should have an `operator[]`.

I have only just started working with them, and so perhaps I have not fully understood something. The application is for "caffe" (machine learning program) data files. (I am trying to use them to write datafiles which caffe can then read.)

I have this line of code in my program (1)

```
datumFloatData->operator[](caffe_ix) = (float)(0.5 * (z_pos + 1.0));
```

defined by

```
google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>* datumFloatData = \
    datum.mutable_float_data();
```

this compiles ok:

```
for(int32_t ix{0}; ix < ix_max; ++ ix)
{
    datumFloatData->Add(-1.0f);
}
```

however (1) does not compile, the error is:

```
error: ‘class google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>’ has no member
named ‘operator[]’; did you mean ‘operator=’?
    datumFloatData->operator[](caffe_ix) = (float)(0.5 * (z_pos + 1.0));
```

What's going on here? I can use the `Add()` method without issue, but `operator[]` is not defined?

Edit: This also does not work:

```
google::protobuf::RepeatedField<float>& \ 
    datumFloatData_ref{*datumFloatData};
datumFloatData_ref[2] = 1.0f;
```

## Edit 2: A fix that works

```
*datumFloatData->Mutable(caffe_ix) = (float)(0.5 * (z_pos + 1.0));
```

Comment: `operator[ ]` is usually called as just `object [ index ]`, not `object.operator[](index)`. You may want `auto& datumFloatData = *datum.mutable_float_data();`

Comment: @MSalters See edit

Comment: What version of the protobuf library are you using?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop `apt policy libprotobuf-dev` reports `3.0.0-9 500` (Debian 9)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an older version of protobuf. A quick check shows that `operator[]` is a trivial wrapper around `Get`, and fairly new. [It was added 2016-09-16](https://github.com/google/protobuf/commit/cc8ca5b6a5478b40546d4206392eb1471454460d)

Comment: That link doesn't appear to contain any relevent information

Comment: @user3728501That is a big commit, but it is the commit which adds `operator[]` to `RepeatedField`. [Here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blame/25a90e82fff6acee900394059432cdb5896cd27d/src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h#L133)'s the exact line which was added in the commit.  Protobuf 3.2 was the first version to include this change.  It simply calls `Get(index)`, which you should be able to do instead of using `operator[]`, unless you want to install protobuf from another repository.  Might be worth updating this answer since it seems to be `Get` and not `Add`.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Ah I now realize why I was confused. I saw the "Get" method in the docs. but since the data was passed const it wasn't the right function to use - but now I can see there is also "mutable" - which is the function I am looking for. (Probably?)

Comment: @CandyGumdrop: Updated `Get`